# SSRS: Subtotal on filtered row

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've a custom Invoice that I'm building and it's divided up into four sections.  I have built the data set so that it has the following data:

Code, Earnings, Rate, Cost, Total, Section

My stored procedure attaches a section based on criteria in within.
I placed a table on the report and added the first 4 data elements and then put a row visibility constraint on it based on section <> 1.  Then I added three more tables to the report, each instead having the row visibility constraint <> 2,3,4.

All this displays properly.

Now in each table, i want to subtotal only the rows that are visible based on the filter.  But when I try to do a sum, I get the "grand total" of all rows(unfiltered).

In the sample picture below you can see the 4 sections and the red circles show where `=SUM(Fields!Total.Value)` display the "grand total".  The values should be:

17,887.55
0
32.48
22.86

Ideas?

Thanks,

PS It won't let me display the image of my report, so i have it here on my Microsoft Exchange OneDrive: http://1drv.ms/1HPXdgO

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a row group on “**wc code/Description**”. You just need to pass **scope (name of the row group)** in your sum method. So your method will look like:
**=SUM(Fields!Total.Value,””)**

Comment: Actually, I'm not using any row groups.  I have 4 tables.  Each table is bound to the same data, however, the data row of the table has a visibility filter on it that reads:

=Fields!Section.Value <> 1

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to solve the problem though it's a work around rather than actually doing what I wanted SSRS to do.

I added four more records to my stored procedure each one grouping by section and forcing a section 101, 102, 103, and 104 to correspond to sections 1, 2, 3, and 4.  Then a fifth record is added to correspond to the grand total record and section 1000 is used to denote this.

Then I added 4 more tables(each having only one row) to the report each filtering on 101, 102, 103, and 104 respectively and the grand total table filtering on 1000.

This makes the report function as per my requirements.  If anyone knows how to do it in the report designer, please reply and i'll mark as solution.